# Send state of all generated checkboxes to Controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

In my view I have created a few checkboxes in a foreach loop and was wondering how I can send the state of these checkboxes (representing true or false) to the controller.

The loop:

```
foreach (dynamic json in Model.Json)
        {
            {<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_class" name="@json.Name" id="check" /><a href="/Home/About?Name=@json.Name"> @json.Name </a><br>}
        }
```

I have tried to find a way using a form using url.action, but I have no clue how to send the state of all the checkboxes generated by the foreach loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share some relevant code.

Comment: How does your Model look like ? What type is Json property ?

Comment: @Shyju Does that matter? In there I convert json files into dynamic objects and put them in a List (using json.net)